# What are the possible reasons of violin bow jumping?

Tags: technique, violin, bow

I am a beginner that is learning to play the violin. Sometimes my bow is "jumping" out of my control. This seems to depend on my right hand, as it does it only sometimes, not every time I play.

What are possible reasons of this unwanted bow jumping?

Comment: What do you mean by jumping? Is the sound skipping when  you change directions, or on steady long bows? Or is the bow completely jumping out of your hand?

Comment: @Karen Steady long bows, kind of like spiccato.

Answer (score 3):

Pay attention to:

- Bow hold -- watch this:

- Bow angle -- If your bow leans too far forward, you might be having control issues.
- Possibly most importantly, Bow Arm -- Your arm should move at the elbow joint, not the whole arm. Push your elbow out so that the bow travels straight across the strings. Check out this video:

- Practice in front of the mirror, **and** record yourself with a smartphone or similar device. Replay these recordings and observe what you can improve.

If you find a solution, do us a favor and make a post of some kind with how you solved the problem for future viewers. I'm curious to know too!

(You *do* have a private teacher, right? Having a private teacher, or even just an experienced peer to critique your form is invaluable.)

Answer (score 2):

My answer assumes that you've taken some violin lessons; the action of the bow arm is very specific and complex, and I can't do it justice in text.  There's just so much to teach.  That being said,

You're probably not putting enough weight on the bow.  The weight of your arm should be concentrated on the part of the bow beneath your index finger; this is only possible if your forearm, elbow, and wrist are aligned the way they're supposed to be.  In addition, you want to increase the weight as you approach the end of the stroke.  Don't force the pressure, just let the arm-wrist-hand unit rest more heavily on the bow, and it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

loosen the knob/screw that's at the end of it. Its purpose is to tighten or loosen the hair. [image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried with the loose hair and the problem is still there. I am aware that tension can be one of the reasons, could you provide other?